# What does the norm $\|\cdot\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d\times d}}$ look like?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, matrix-norms

I want to know how to compute the norm given by $\|\cdot\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d\times d}}$ on the space $L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d\times d}$ of $d\times d$ matrices whose entries are $L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)-$functions. Here $d\in\mathbb N_{0}$ and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^{d}$ open. I have **never** understood how to compute any norm given on any space of matrices, and struggle to see how this particular norm should look like. What does $\|\cdot\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d\times d}}$ look like?

I know that for the space $L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d}$ the norm is just the sum of the $d-$copies of the standard $L^{2}-$norms on the respective entries of a given $f\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d}$, and looks like
$$\|f\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d}}=\|f_{1}\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{}}+\dots+\|f_{d}\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{}}.$$

Is this norm in some way related to the norm $\|\cdot\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d\times d}}$ which I want to compute? I have heard that the space $L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d\times d}$ is unitarily equivalent to $L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{dd}$ (although I don't know how to prove this), which would perhaps provide such a relation.

Comment: You cn pretty much take any norm on $\mathbb{C}^{d \times d}$ and tensor it with the $L^2$-norm to get a norm on $L^2(\Omega)^{d \times d}$. Without more context it is difficult to tell which norm you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $\|\cdot\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d\times d}}$ is actually very similar to the one for $\|\cdot\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d}}$ you gave.

Indeed, for $f \in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d\times d}$ as you defined it, $\|f\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d\times d}}$ is given by
$$\|f\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d\times d}}^2 := \int_\Omega |f(x)|^2 d\mu (x) $$

Where $|f(x)|^2:=\sum_{1\le i,j\le d} f_{i,j}(x)^2 $ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Also notice that, because all $f_{i,j}$ are square integrable and the sum is finite, we can write
$$\begin{align*}\|f\|_{L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)^{d\times d}}^2 &=\int_\Omega |f(x)|^2 d\mu (x)\\
&= \int_\Omega\left( \sum_{1\le i,j\le d} f_{i,j}(x)^2\right) d\mu(x)\\
&= \sum_{1\le i,j\le d} \int_\Omega f_{i,j}(x)^2 d\mu(x)\\
&= \sum_{1\le i,j\le d} \|f_{i,j}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2
\end{align*} $$
Which is essentially the same expression as the one for vector-valued functions, and it can similarly be extended to higher orders too.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the definition of this norm, or is this quite standard?

Comment: You are lacking squares on the left sides of your equations.

Comment: SarahPaulson's Scream : I don't have a good reference at hand unfortunately, I've mainly seen it discussed when talking about Sobolev norms, such as page 18 of [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/acta-numerica/article/an-optimal-control-approach-to-a-posteriori-error-estimation-in-finite-element-methods/5C67A03F528C6FA69F37A97DF5C3BE19/share/2dc07952b37455f2d8d8914241c0acd8976d2f31) by Becker and Rannacher.  
@MaoWao : thanks, I just added them !